# What does Terraform consider a "cluster" in VCenter?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-vsphere

Terraform v1.0.x, ESXi v6.x

I'm trying to create a VM, and this is part of my plan

```
data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = var.cluster
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name             = var.vm_name
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id

  clone {
     template_uuid  = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id
  }
  ...
}
```

But what does Terraform consider a "cluster?" I see the following in VSphere

```
> vcenter2.mydomain.com
  > Dev
  > QA
  > Production
```

From my understanding, `Dev`, `QA`, and `Production` are "clusters," but passing those a the cluster name doesn't work.

Anyway to find out via Terraform `data` statement what our Vcenter's clusters are maybe? Thanks.

Comment: If you search for VMWare/VSphere documentation, you can find various short articles about compute clusters. These are sometimes actually not even necessary and typically differ slightly by design, but the easiest path forward here is to talk to the VMWare admin(s) you are working with to assist with that environment's compute clusters usage and definition. I typically just do that to fulfill any requirements around that before moving on. Also, the list you posted in the question looks like datacenters.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yes I would call those data centers also, but my VMware IT person calls them clusters.

Comment: So this then becomes more of an unfortunate cultural problem where the VMWare SME does not know the terminology, and you have to figure out the API hierarchy yourself. From a VSphere API perspective, you may not even have or need compute clusters if you have independent resource pools and only manage VSphere resources (e.g. virtual machines, datastores, etc.) that do not require compute clusters.